# PHP: Stop Implode once condition is met

Tags: php, implode

Is there a way to stop an implode once a certain condition is met?  I can't find anything in any of the docs.  This code is producing an output that looks like this:

```
 page  --->  page  --->  $goal ---> page  --->  $goal
 page  --->  $goal ---> page ---> page
```

and I want it to only run until the first $goal appears and then move onto the next line, so it's the last one like this:

```
page  --->  page  --->  $goal
page  --->  $goal
```

Here is the portion of my code with the implode.  I tired sticking an if statement with a break just before the echo.. but that did nothing.

```
$goalpage = "leadfactory.ca/analytics/goal.php";

$html = "<table>";
$html .= "<tr><th align='left'>PAGE PATHS HITTING GOAL.PHP</th></tr>";
$paths = array();
$sql = "SELECT cookie_uid, page_url FROM pageviews WHERE cookie_uid ORDER BY rowid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$got_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($got_rows) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

// Create an array for the cookie_uid if it doesn't exist yet
if ( ! array_key_exists($row['cookie_uid'], $paths) || ! is_array($paths[$row['cookie_uid']])) {
    $paths[$row['cookie_uid']] = [];
}

// Add to the array now that we know it exists
array_push($paths[$row['cookie_uid']], $row['page_url']);
}

foreach ($paths as $session => $page) {
if ($page == $goalpage) {
    break;
}
   echo "<tr><td>" . implode('  --->   ', $page) . "</td></tr>";
}

} else {
$html .= '<td colspan="2">No results</td>' . "";
}

$html .= "</table>";
echo $html;

if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))  {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: what do you mean that did nothing? that is the right thing to do.

Comment: What is the value of `$paths`?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Your starting array
$pages = array("page","page","page","page","page","goal","page","page",);

// Get the index of the "goal" key
// see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php
$lastkey = array_search("goal", $pages);

// Shorten your array accordingly
// see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php
$pages = array_slice($pages, 0, $lastkey+1);

// Implode
implode(' ---> ', $pages);
```

fiddle: https://3v4l.org/CIAH5

No, you can't "stop" implode, but you can mess with your array before you implode...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$arr[0]="page0";
$arr[1]="page1";
$arr[2]="page2";
$arr[3]="goal";
$arr[4]="page4";


echo implode(" ---> ", array_slice($arr, 0, array_search("goal",$arr)+1));
```

outputs

```
page0 ---> page1 ---> page2 ---> goal
```

See it in action
https://3v4l.org/cFhv3

the function would be:

```
function implode_with_limit($arr, $goal)
{
    return implode(" ---> ", array_slice($arr, 0, array_search($goal,$arr)+1));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be giving me just the first page only for each row.

foreach ($paths as $session => $page) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . implode(" ---> ", array_slice($page, 0, array_search($goal,$page)+1)) . "</td></tr>";
    //echo "<tr><td>" . implode('  --->   ', $page) . "</td></tr>";
    }

Comment: @Topher you dont need foreach. use it like `echo "<tr><td>".implode_with_limit($paths,"goal")."</td></tr>";` where `"goal"` whatever is your stop value.